# How to set diff options (--compaction-heuristic) in gitk

Tags: git, git-diff, gitk

The git 2.9 release came with an experimental diff algorithm `--compaction-heuristic`. I've set up git, and git gui to use this.

However I can't figure out how to configure gitk to use this option. I'm aware of the `.gitk` config file, but I can't figure out how configure diff options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting diff.compactionHeuristic true in your git config should be picked up by gitk.

```
git config --global diff.compactionHeuristic true
```